# Use jquery from window.top inside iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

In a project, we have to use the jquery provided by some platform, and our code is running inside an iframe.

In our code, when we use jquery to find some element, we have to provide `window.document` every time:

```
const $ = window.top.$
$('#btn1', window.document).click(...)
$('#btn2', window.document).click(...)
$('#btn3', window.document).click(...)
```

If I missed one, there will be some trick bugs.

Is there any way to "bind" the `$` from `window.top` to current document? I'm looking for a way like:

```
const $ = window.top.$

$.bindOrSomething(window.document)

$('#btn1').click(...)
$('#btn2').click(...)
$('#btn3').click(...)
```